# How can I configure scheduled virtual machine backup?

Tags: cron, backup, kvm, qemu

I have a box with:

- Debian 8.3 Jessie in minimal config
- 16 Gb RAM
- 4-core Intel SandyBridge 2.5 Ghz
- 2 x 300 Gb SAS in RAID10 (using hardware controller)
- qemu-kvm and virt-manager are installed
- Network interfaces are configured to allow remote access via SSH (putty)

A single virtual machine (windows server 2012) has been created in hypervisor with the following setup:
- 16 Gb RAM, 4 cores (all host resources)
- 2 disk images (*.qed) placed in /var/lib/libvirt/images/ (50 Gb and 100 Gb), both sparsed
- In windows, 50 Gb disk is used as a system disk (for OS) and 100 Gb as a data disk

I plan to add one more disk (the same SAS 300 Gb).

I want to secure myself and make a backup of virtual machine.

What is the best way to achieve this?
Below are the details of how I see it (subject to discussion/change):

1. Schedule a timely shutdown of a virtual machine (during the night) - first task scheduler in windows (graceful shutdown) and then cron in debian
2. Make a backup of a virtual machine to the newly attached disk - I'd prefer to have a full and diff backup on a regular basis (e.g. full every week (on sunday), diff every day)
3. Turn on the virtual machine and start the guest OS